# Electron app that contains Node.js server backend with React front end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am new to Electron and want to build an app that bundles a NodeJS server and React front end. My NodeJs/React structure looks very similar to this:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

I need to take a structure like this (client, server) and build a single Electron app that starts the server for the client. The many examples I've found only focus on Electron and React, or Electron and Node.js, but not all three (Electron, NodeJs and React).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not a good practice to manage the server on a client's end ex, security concerns. better you can create a separate repo for server and desktop applications.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I'm struggling with the same situation

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact scenario which I was looked 3 months before. Please find my solutions from below.

**You can publish your node js (backend) server as a npm package then you can install it in your react app inside electron.js file.** so that it serves API to your react app.

Find my setup from below.

Node js (package.json)

```
"main": "dist/server.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000 -b test",
    "build": "grunt",
    "prepublish": "npm run build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
```

Step 1 : npm install -> Will download necessary packages and then build it using grunt compiler. A distribution folder will create (dist).

Folder structure FYR

[image]

Step2 : npm publish -> For this you must have to already create npm account. With help of this your can able to publish your server as a node package manager.

React electron (Client side):

Step 1 : Install your newly created NPM package in front end.
Step 2 : Import that inside electron.js file.

[image]

After that once you click on your exe file, Your server will also get started to serve the API's.

Hope it helps. Feel free to ask, if you have any issues with this. My desktop app is in live now, and it working fine as well.